# Sharepoint Calendar does not show up on my Outlook 2013 calendar as busy

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, outlook

My goal is to create a Sharepoint calendar that I can have on my calendar.  I would like for my calendar to update as the Sharepoint calendar updates.  So, I have created a calendar on my Sharepoint site.  I have connected my Sharepoint calendar with my Outlook 2013 using the "Connect to Outlook" option.

When others view my calendar, they do not see that I am busy during the events on the Sharepoint Calendar.  Is it possible to make the Sharepoint calendar show up as busy on my calendar?

Comment: Not directly, you typically had to drag the events from your SP calendar into your outlook calendar. The overlays are not integrating them into a single consolidated calendar.